# How to prove in SOL the validity of the identity of indiscernibles?

Tags: logic, identity

I found an exercise page 126 of the book 'Logic for Philosophy' by Sider. The exercise asks to prove in second-order logic the identity of indiscernibles. I tried to write a proof ex absurdo, but I cannot find the contradiction in the hypothesis that the principle is false. I attach the demonstration: which step is missing?

[image]

Comment: Use the SOL definition of identity.

Comment: Why can 'a = b' be defined as 'For all X (Xa iff Xb)'? Does this not require a further demonstration?

Comment: The def of identity is "two objects are identical iff they share all ppropertjes". From this Identity of indiscernibles immediately follows.

Comment: My question is: Why is identity defined in that way?

Comment: Because if two thins are different, i.e. not identical, they differ in some aspect.

Comment: This is the famous [Leibniz law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles)...